# Firebase never connects from React Native on iOS (simulator)

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

Not able to connect to firebase from React Native. I can see that it keeps retrying, but never succeeds. Has anybody successfully connected to firebase from React native ? This is on a iOS 9 simulator.

> Firebase Debug Logs:

---

```
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.018 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'p:0: Browser went online.  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.025 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'p:0: Listen called for /appversions default  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.026 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'p:0: Listen called for /systemstatus/message default  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.032 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'p:0: Making a connection attempt  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.033 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:0: Connection created  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.036 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:0:0 Websocket connecting to wss://<app-name>.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.038 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.RCTWebSocketManagerQueue][RCTSRWebSocket.m:520] SocketRocket: In debug mode.  Allowing connection to any root cert2015-10-22 12:58:31.815 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:0:0 Websocket connected.  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.816 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:0:0 Websocket connection was disconnected.  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.816 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:0:0 WebSocket is closing itself  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.817 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:0: Closing realtime connection.  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.817 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:0: Shutting down all connections  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.817 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'p:0: data client disconnected  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.818 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'p:0: Trying to reconnect in 112.12895049713552ms  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.819 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] '0: onDisconnectEvents  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.932 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'p:0: Making a connection attempt  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.933 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:1: Connection created  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.934 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:1:0 Websocket connecting to wss://<app-name>.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:31.934 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.RCTWebSocketManagerQueue][RCTSRWebSocket.m:520] SocketRocket: In debug mode.  Allowing connection to any root cert
    2015-10-22 12:58:32.698 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:1:0 Websocket connected.  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:32.699 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:1:0 Websocket connection was disconnected.  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:32.699 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:1:0 WebSocket is closing itself  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:32.699 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:1: Closing realtime connection.  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:32.699 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:1: Shutting down all connections  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:32.700 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'p:0: data client disconnected  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:32.700 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'p:0: Trying to reconnect in 28.659726264886558ms  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:32.701 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] '0: onDisconnectEvents  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:32.732 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'p:0: Making a connection attempt  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:32.732 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:2: Connection created  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:32.733 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'c:0:2:0 Websocket connecting to wss://<app-name>.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5  '
    2015-10-22 12:58:32.733 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.RCTWebSocketManagerQueue][RCTSRWebSocket.m:520] SocketRocket: In debug mode.  Allowing connection to any root cert
```

Comment: I've been able to include firebase in my iOS project, both from simulator and device. I've not facedhis issue

Comment: Can you try with the latest react-native?  I believe this was fixed by https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/607527c0d4bf6d8197829f3523c4d937ac71ed07 but I'm not sure what release that made it into...

Answer (score 0):

just a thought in the log it states:

```
 Websocket connecting to wss://<app-name>.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5
```

maybe you need to configure the firebase app name, or does it show that regardless?

Comment: I removed the actual name from the log

Comment: Thought that was too obvious :p

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a bug with the react-native WebSocket polyfill and should be fixed in the latest bits (by https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/607527c0d4bf6d8197829f3523c4d937ac71ed07).  Please try updating and see if the problem goes away!

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you have enabled Public read access on your Firebase DB. 
[Firebase Db setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqwqu.png)